# Generic Enum Function Parameters?

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I have many different enums, for example:

```
enum Fruit {
    case apple, pear, banana, melon
}

enum Wood {
    case oak, birch, mahogany
}
```

I want to write a static function to compare if two specified generic enum values are the same.

```
funct myCmp<T>(a: T, b: T) -> Bool {
    return a == b // cannot compare generic types
}
```

How can this be done? In Java this is easily done without any additional code, which is why I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a much broader definition of equality. Any two objects can be compared. This has obvious benefits, but it comes with a lot of complexities and draw backs. For example:

- Most objects only compare equally to objects of the same class, so you end up repeating a lot of boilerplate in every implementation of `equals()`, like:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
      // self check
      if (this == o)
          return true;
      // null check
      if (o == null)
          return false;
      // type check and cast
      if (getClass() != o.getClass())
          return false;
      Person person = (Person) o;

      // ACTUAL comparison starts here.
  }
  ```
- It's really easy to introduce subtle but very confusing bugs, which stem from accidentally asymmetrical implementations of `equals`. You have to make sure that every implementation of `Equals` meets the invariant that `a.equals(b) == b.equals(a)`. Since the types of `a` and `b` can be different, this becomes very easy to mess up in large systems.

  - It seldom makes sense, and it's rarely useful. Consider your case: `Fruit.apple` is not equal to `Wood.oak`, however you slice it. The comparison is non-sense.

Swift's model is much more locked down. If you look at `Equatable`, it stipulates that both parameters have type `Self`. The two of the three checks in the Java code above (that the parameter is non null, and that its types matches) aren't necessary, because it's literally impossible to convince the type system to provide a `nil` or wrongly typed object as a parameter to `==`.

---

One total misunderstanding later:

You *can* write a function that compares any objects of a (single) generic type `T`, but what you were missing was a constant that `T` be equatable. Without knowing `T` is equatable, your function can't be certain that an appropriate `==` even exists.

Here's your example:

```
func myCmp<T: Equatable>(a: T, b: T) -> Bool {
    return a == b
}
```

For the more concrete example in your comment, I would use an extension on `Sequence`, rather than a function:

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable {
    func allEqual(to desiredElement: Element) -> Bool {
        for element in self {
            if element != desiredElement { return false }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

and use it like `[fruitA, fruitB, fruitC].allEqual(to: .apple)`

Comment: Thank you for you detailed post. In my actual code I have four enums each with four values. I want to define a function that takes three enum values of the same type and return `true` if they are all different from each other. Meaning I can call `diff(apple, pear, apple) // false`, `diff(monday, tuesday, friday) // true` `diff(oak, oak, oak) // false`

Comment: @Hatefiend Oh, that's easy. (As you can see) I thought you were trying to compare across types. I'll update my answer.

Comment: See my update. Also, unrelated but important: 1) don't write function names like `myCmp`. Keystrokes are free. Write something meaningful 2) don't use parameter labels that don't add value like `a:` and `b:`. Omit them with `func f(_ a: T, _ b: T)`, 3) don't use a name like `diff`. Diff is both a verb and a noun, and it's not clear which it should act like in the way you're using it. If I saw a function named `diff`, I would expect it to do a deep comparison of objects, and return me some sort of summary of the differences, not a `bool`.